# ES6 Modules - why named const exports are not read only

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, es6-modules

I've been [reading about ES modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html) and experimenting and stumbled upon a case I couldn't explain:

```
// settings.js
export const FOO = 42;
export const BAR= 5;

// main1.js
import * as settings from './settings';
settings.FOO = 1;

//main2.js
import {FOO, BAR} from './settings'
FOO = 1;
```

In `main1.js` I'm able to override the `const` value through the `settings` variable, but in `main2.js` I can't (as expected).

The (theoretical) question is why in the first case it's possible to override the `const` value? Does creating a "read only view" simply creates properties on a regular object and breaks the original structure?

The practical question would be what's the most effective way to return a collection of constants (or read only properties) from a module? What I had in mind is this:

```
// settings.js
export default Object.freeze({
  FOO: 42,
  BAR: 5
});
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: I'm using Babel.

Comment: You never say in your question, what implementation of modules are you using? Because the answer to this entirely depends on the compiler you are using.

Comment: @loganfsmyth It's Babel, do you think it's a bug in the implementation?

Comment: I don't think we have a specific bug for it, though it's definitely a known deficiency. If you'd like to file it, you are welcome to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The other answer is incorrect.

> The (theoretical) question is why in the first case it's possible to override the const value?

This is actually entirely independent of `const`. With ES6 module syntax, you are not allowed to reassign the exported value of a module, from outside the module. The same would be true with `export let FOO;` or `export var FOO;`. Code *inside* the module is the only thing that is allowed to change exports.

Doing `settings.FOO = 1` technically should throw an exception, but most compilers don't handle this particular edge case currently.

As an example, you could do

```
export var FOO;

export function setFoo(value){
  FOO = value;
}
```

and given this, *this* is when `const` becomes useful because it's the same as any other normal JS code. `FOO = value` would fail if it was declared as `export const FOO`, so if your module is exporting a bunch of constants, doing `export const FOO = 1, FOO2 = 2;` is a good way to export constants, it's just that Babel doesn't actually make them immutable.

Comment: This was the original way I wanted to go, but when testing I realised the values are overridden when doing `import * as settings`

Answer (score 2):

In this code

```
import * as settings from './settings';
settings.FOO = 1;
```

In the above code, you are not assigning directly to the constant variable but a cloned copy in `settings`.

```
import * as settings from './settings';
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
settings.FOO = 1;
```

But it is not the case in the next code

```
import {FOO, BAR} from './settings'
FOO = 1;
```

Here `FOO` and `BAR` are constants and you can't assign to it.

Comment: "you are not assigning directly to the constant variable but a cloned copy in settings" That is the case with Babel specifically, but that is not the behavior defined in the ES spec. `settings.FOO = 1;` should throw an exception in reality.